# Validating string input and concatenating it to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

```
studentNumber = len(age) - 1
age[studentNumber] = 0
house[studentNumber] = ''
reactionTime[studentNumber] = 0

while True:
  try:
    age[studentNumber] = int(input("What is the age of the student: "))
  except ValueError:
    age[studentNumber] = int(input("What is the age of the student: "))

  if age[studentNumber] in range(12, 17):
    break

house[studentNumber] = input("Which house is the student in (Saturn/Mars): ").lower()
while house[studentNumber] not in {"saturn", "mars"}:
  house[studentNumber] = input("Which house is the student in (Saturn/Mars): ").lower()

age.append(0)
house.append('')
reactionTime.append(0)

print(age + " " + house + " " + reactionTime)
```

I'm trying to validate the input as a string that is "saturn"or "mars", but I'm receiving the error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` when I try to add it to my list

The command line:

```
What would you like to do:
1. Enter new information
2. House-based statsitics
3. Specific Criteria statistics
Enter 1 2 or 3:  1
What is the age of the student:  12
Which house is the student in (Saturn/Mars):  saturn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 46, in <module>
  File "python", line 32, in newInfo
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: Please post all of your code. None of the code you posted can raise the error you're getting.

Comment: @Loocid Updated it

Comment: @YousifAlnajjar Are `age`, `house` and `reactionTime` all lists? In the updated code you have posted they are undefined.

Comment: @MatthewSmith They're defined as globals

Comment: I guess they will be lists since they are appended to lower in the code, with the studentNumber being the index?

Comment: I think `age + " " + house + " " + reactionTime` is supposed to be `age[studentNumber] + " " + house[studentNumber] + " " + reactionTime[studentNumber]`?

Comment: @YousifAlnajjar Are they lists?

Comment: How are you executing your script and what is the complete output it generates? Seeing the full error trace is helpful.

Comment: @SvenH. Yeah that's it

Comment: @MatthewSmith Yes

Comment: I don't want to have to run your script. Why don't you update your question with the command-line you are using to run your script and post the output that results.

Comment: @RedCricket Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`age`, `house` and `reactionTime` are lists and cannot be concatenated with strings.

You should zip the three lists and iterate through the items for output.

Change:

```
print(age + " " + house + " " + reactionTime)
```

to:

```
for a, h, r in zip(age, house, reactionTime):
    print(a, h, r)
```